# Can I give a custom-enchanted dwarven item to Calcelmo for his quest?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

In Skyrim, I've accidentally lost the Dwarven Sword of Devouring needed by Calcelmo. I have tried to craft a Dwarven, one handed sword, enchanted with 15 points of Absorption - which should equate to "devouring", but Calcelmo won't take it from me (literally).

I know I can steal Mercers sword of the same, but what am I doing wrong with the crafting?

Answer (score 4):

Calcelmo requires an item that is the same as the one he mentions in the letter (it doesn't have to be the same item, though). Player-enchanted items are not the same as items found in the world, so it won't work, you'll need to find another Dwarven Sword of Devouring to give to Calcelmo. If he asked you for a non-enchanted item, smithing it will work.

If you're playing on PC, you can use the console command `help "dwarven sword of devouring"` to find the baseid (8 digit code) of that item, then use `player.additem baseid 1` to give yourself a copy of that sword.